# .innerHTML opera issue?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, opera

I'm trying to do :

```
document.getElementById("header-text").innerHTML = "something interesting";
```

It's working fine with every browser except Opera (I'm running the latest version).

Browsing the internet I found people saying that Opera does not support innerHTML. That doesn't sound right.

Any pointers?

Thanks

**Edit**: Here is the id I'm trying to get

```
<div id="header-text" class="picture-text">
          <!--[if gt IE 5]>ugly hack<![endif]-->
          Some text generated server side
         <!--[if gt IE 5]>ugly hack<![endif]-->
</div>
```

**Edit2**: I have the same issue with :

```
<div id="header-text" class="picture-text">
          Static text
</div>
```

**Edit3**:

```
<body onload="intialize();">


function intialize() {
    operaHeaderFix();
}


function operaHeaderFix(){
    if(window.opera) {
        /*opera specific action*/ 
        document.getElementById("picture-line-wrapper").style.position="relative";
        document.getElementById("picture-line-wrapper").style.top="0px";
        document.getElementById("picture-line-wrapper").style.marginTop="-230px";
        document.getElementById("picture-line").style.padding="1px";
        document.getElementById("header-text").innerHTML = "<div style='margin:220px 0px 0px 20px;'>"+document.getElementById("header-text").innerHTML+"TEST</div>";
    }
}
```

**Edit4**: If I remove the if(window.opera), it will run fine in FF and IE

Comment: What exact version of Opera do you have?

Comment: I have  9.64 running on Windows XP

Comment: I just updated to 9.64 (on XP) and ran your static div/JS test... and it worked fine. There must be something else going on.

Comment: there is something real fishy going on, as all the above bits work for me... (edits 1-4)

Comment: This is working for me in Opera as well.  All I can suggest at this point is to uninstall and reinstall Opera and see if it works then.

Comment: Confirmed. On the actual site, Opera is throwing an error that it can't convert undefined or null into an object when operaHeaderFix() is being called.... why though? I'm still not sure...

Comment: Ok, a little closer...  the .innerHTML property is defined on the 3 parent elements of the header-text... but throws the error on the "header-text" element. e.g. it thinks the .innerHTML property does not exist on that element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***FOUND THE ISSUE:***

The wrapping node was not properly closed.

```
<div att1="value" att2="value"
  <div id="header-text">...</div>
</div>
```

AFAIK, FF and IE were politely fixing the tag... but Opera wasn't, thus the child DIV wasn't really an element in the DOM.

---

Should work fine.  What is the element with the id "header-text"? Are you sure there is only one match, and it has editable content?

Can you post some of the markup so we can test?

From PPK's site, there doesn't seem to be any Opera issues:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html

***Update:*** Running this code in Opera 9.6.4 on XP works fine for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>innerHTML test</title>
<script>
  function doIt(){
    document.getElementById("header-text").innerHTML = "something interesting";
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header-text" class="picture-text">
    Static text
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Change It" onclick="doIt();"/><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the only match. There are conditional comments (<!--[if gt IE 5]> etc) in it thought, could that be a problem?

Comment: this is really weird... Updated the question to include how I call the function. Thanks for your help

Comment: that was some great debugging ! thanks again. I feel bad for leaving such a terrible mistake in the code and not even thinking of looking for it !

Comment: no worries it happens to us all.  I too was so focused on that 1 element that I didn't think much about its context.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a somewhat related issue and found it to be related to HTML encoded values.  For example, when the innerHTML contained "&nbsp;" instead of a space, the innerHTML would come back slightly different (which I confirmed by testing the length of the innerHTML).

Here is what I found when trying to get the innerHTML of a tag that contained a single DIV wrapping an encoded non-breaking space (<div>&nbsp;</div>):

```
<div> </div>
```

The example above shows how Opera 10.26 would return innerHTML, and when I checked the length it would return 12 in Opera

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

This is how all other browsers I used would return innerHTML (IE6/7/8, Firefox 3.x, Chrome, etc.), and when I checked the length it would return 17 in all these other browsers.

Comment: (This is a known bug in Opera, should get fixed for Opera 11 or shortly after)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: How are you calling this function?  Are you calling it in the document `<head>`, at the end of the `<body>`, are you using `window.onload`?

`innerHTML` is not a w3c-valid attribute (it will be in HTML 5).  It was created by Microsoft and is just supported by *most* other browsers for compatibility reasons.

That said, I believe Opera does support `innerHTML`, however some googling suggests that it [is broken in certain versions](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=717637).  Try updating your version of Opera and see if it works then.

Comment: Like I said, I'm using the latest version of Opera

Comment: (I saw this forum post while googling and updated ^^ Didn't fix anything though)